# String строку даты преобразовать в Date

Tags: java, дата, simpledateformat

Есть такие даты в String, как преобразовать в Date date?

7 авг 2019

7 авг. 2019

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String data2 = "7 янв. 2019";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale("ru"));
Date date = formatter.parse(data2.replaceAll("\\.",""));
```

Answer (score -1):

Данный ответ не идеален. Но за костыль сойдет

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data1 = "7 янв 2019";
        String data2 = "7 янв. 2019";

        System.out.println(dateConvertor(data1));
        System.out.println(dateConvertor(data2));
    }

    public static Date dateConvertor(String date){

        List<String> month = new ArrayList<>();
        month.add("янв");
        //добавить еще 11 месяцев

        //Делим на 3 части - день/месяц/год
        String[] dateArray = date.split(" ");

        //удаляем точку
        dateArray[1] = dateArray[1].replaceAll("\\.", "");

        //заменяем месяц на английское слово
        dateArray[1] = String.valueOf(month.indexOf(dateArray[1]) + 1);

        Date dateResult = null;
        try {
            dateResult =  new SimpleDateFormat("d M yyyy").parse(dateArray[0] + " " + dateArray[1] + " " + dateArray[2]);
        } catch (ParseException e){
        }

        return dateResult;

    }
```